# Javascript Web Token can't be access through my lumen backend

Tags: php, laravel, ldap, jwt, lumen

I'm following this tutorial https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/jwt-authentication-for-lumen-5-6-2376fd38d454 to learn how to setup a tokenbased authentication for my lumen backend.

So far, everything worked fine. Only in the end it turns out that I cant get a token Oo
I don't think that theres anything wrong with my code. 
When using RESTClient to do an http-Request to: "http://localhost:8080/users"
I get the desired "'error' : 'Token not provided'"

However, when I try to get the token as described in the tutorial, I get errors that the name and e-mail field aren't provided.
Here is my controller code (or the code from the tutorial) which evaluates the request for the transmitted name and email values:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Validator;
use App\User;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Firebase\JWT\ExpiredException;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
class AuthController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * The request instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Http\Request
     */
    private $request;
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    /**
     * Create a new token.
     *
     * @param  \App\User   $user
     * @return string
     */
    protected function jwt(User $user) {
        $payload = [
            'iss' => "lumen-jwt", // Issuer of the token
            'sub' => $user->id, // Subject of the token
            'iat' => time(), // Time when JWT was issued.
            'exp' => time() + 60*60 // Expiration time
        ];

        // As you can see we are passing `JWT_SECRET` as the second parameter that will
        // be used to decode the token in the future.
        return JWT::encode($payload, env('JWT_SECRET'));
    }
    /**
     * Authenticate a user and return the token if the provided credentials are correct.
     *
     * @param  \App\User   $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function authenticate(User $user) {
        $this->validate($this->request, [
            'email'     => 'required|email',
            'password'  => 'required'
        ]);
        // Find the user by email
        $user = User::where('email', $this->request->input('email'))->first();
        if (!$user) {
            // You wil probably have some sort of helpers or whatever
            // to make sure that you have the same response format for
            // differents kind of responses. But let's return the
            // below respose for now.
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Email does not exist.'
            ], 400);
        }
        // Verify the password and generate the token
        if (Hash::check($this->request->input('password'), $user->password)) {
            return response()->json([
                'token' => $this->jwt($user)
            ], 200);
        }
        // Bad Request response
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Email or password is wrong.'
        ], 400);
    }
}
```

And here is the code of the middleware:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Exception;
use App\User;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\ExpiredException;
class JwtMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        $token = $request->get('token');

        if(!$token) {
            // Unauthorized response if token not there
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Token not provided.'
            ], 401);
        }
        try {
            $credentials = JWT::decode($token, env('JWT_SECRET'), ['HS256']);
        } catch(ExpiredException $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'Provided token is expired.'
            ], 400);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => 'An error while decoding token.'
            ], 400);
        }
        $user = User::find($credentials->sub);
        // Now let's put the user in the request class so that you can grab it from there
        $request->auth = $user;
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Which I have registered in bootstrap/app.php:

```
 $app->routeMiddleware([
     'jwt.auth' => App\Http\Middleware\JwTMiddleware::class,
 ]);
```

But my JSON Payload looks like this so it SHOULD work.

```
[
  {
    "email": "ibeier@hotmail.com,
    "name": "Eusebio Dach",

  }
]
```

However I must admit that the tutorial in this section was a bit lacking in the details.
Here is that (last) part which I cant get to work:

"
To make this privious request successful we need to provide the token as query parameter. We can get the token by hitting the following route http://localhost:8000/auth/login inside Postman application. Now that you have the token open the priviously failed request and this time in the Params section create a key token and set it’s value to the token that you received in previous request. And after that send the request to http://localhost/users route and you will get the users list in response.
(Screenshot with userdata, see tutorial)
And that about wraps it up. If you have any questions feel free to leave your comments below.
"

I'm not sure whether I provided the correct request data and if I have set all headers correctly. 
Maybe someone with a bit more knowledge in this can help me understanding what I am missing. 
I already tried looking into other tutorials but these take different jwt extensions for their lumen and also seem to take other approaches in their controller code etc.. 
I'd very much like to follow this tutorial since its approach seemed pretty straight-forward to me.
It would also help if someone could tell me that the tutorial worked for them, and maybe also tell me what they did in addition to the instructions provided through the tutorial.
Because then I would just do the tutorial again and see if I can get it working.

Comment: you tell us about an error "name and e-mail field aren't provided" but in your code it looks like email and password are verified.

Comment: @jps yeah that's just one of the many questions I'm facing ^^